# dialogflow chatbot how to go to firestore database and return with support relevant questions?

Tags: firebase, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am using "firestore" database for my "dialogflow" chat bot which I already created for an online grocery store. The problem is: I want my chatbot to initially ask questions from users to find the proper item title in my database and then return to user by asking 3-4 support relevant questions about that item. the questions must be the item attributes (Brand, color, size...) and will vary from one item to another. so the chatbot will stream down the user to find the best item.
can you please help me to find the answer? I already created the codes but they don't work and I do not know what is wrong with that. If you already created this and have the index.js file, I appreciate to propose me here.

```
 index.js:

    'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import admin SDK
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {
  WebhookClient
} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// here we get the database in a variable
const db = admin.firestore();
const data = {...};
// Add a new document in collection "dialogflow" with document ID 'agent'
  const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent').set(data); 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({
    request,
    response
  });
 function writeToDb(agent) {
    // Get parameter from Dialogflow with the string to add to the database doc
    const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.databaseEntry;
  // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent' and store
    // the document  {entry: "<value of database entry>"} in the 'agent' document
      const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent').where('title', '==', title);

    return db.runTransaction(t => {
      t.set(dialogflowAgentRef, {
        entry: databaseEntry
      });
      return Promise.resolve('Write complete');
    }).then(doc => {
      agent.add(`Wrote "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
      agent.add(`Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    });
  }
function readFromDb(agent) {
    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent'
    const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('dialogflow/agent/rss/channel/item'); // .doc('agent')

    // Get the value of 'entry' in the document and send it to the user
    return dialogflowAgentDoc.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          agent.add('No data found in the database!');
        } else {
          agent.add(doc.data().entry);
        }
        return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
      }).catch(() => {
        agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
        agent.add('Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
      });
  }
  // Map from Dialogflow intent names to functions to be run when the intent is matched
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('ReadFromFirestore', readFromDb);
  intentMap.set('WriteToFirestore', writeToDb);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to explain what you mean by how it doesn't work? Is it giving you an error? If so, what is the error? If not, what is it doing that is different than what you expect?

Comment: The agent(dialogflow) entries cannot be written or retrieved from firestore. when I get a value from dialogflow agent, I want it to be written in the right path in my database (i.e: dialogflow/agent/rss/channel/item/5/item). on the other hand, I want my chat bot to go to the title and find other item attributes then return with support relevant questions. this is my database path including portion of data:

Comment: data:https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fulfillmentfirestore/database/fulfillmentfirestore/data                                                                                                                        I just presented the "real time database" here for you to have an idea about hierarchies, although I already use cloud firestore, but value levels are the same.

Comment: so the problem in brief is that it cannot read or write

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code as you've shown it that could cause problems reading and writing with the Firestore database.

It looks like you're trying to find an existing collection to write to with the line

```
const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent').where('title', '==', title);
```

but `title` isn't defined anywhere, which I suspect causes an error. Furthermore, `doc()` returns a [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentReference), but there is no `where()` method in a DocumentReference.

Remember that you need to structure Firestore using alternating collections and documents. So your "firebase" collection can contain a document named "agent", and that document may have subcollections.

When you're trying to read with

```
const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('dialogflow/agent/rss/channel/item');
```

You're getting a collection, but then trying to treat it as a document. The comment suggests that you're trying to read a specific doc from this collection (which makes sense), but you're loading that document by a hard-coded string "agent", rather than trying to get the agent from the parameters passed to you from Dialogflow.

Finally - the paths in the read and write sections don't match. Using hard-coded paths are fine when testing, but make sure you're using matching paths and that they reflect the collection/doc/collection/doc/... path requirement.

So in both cases, you might have a reference that looks something like

```
const docTitle = agent.parameters.title;
const docRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc(title);
```

Which, if you have defined a "title" parameter in your Intents in Dialogflow, will use this to reference the doc, which you can then read or write.

Answer (score -1):

```
thanks for the answer I already changed my database to real time firebase instead of firestore. still having problem with support relevant questions. I want to go to my real time database to find the item by search using "oederByChild" and "equalTo" methods as I found these in people questions and answer in this website. still cannot find and item title through my database child. here is the codes are written:

'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {
    WebhookClient
} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.database();
// const ref = db.ref('server/saving-data/fireblog');
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({
        request,
        response
    });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent' and store
    // the document  {entry: "<value of database entry>"} in the 'agent' document
    function writeToDb(agent) {
        const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.databaseEntry;
        const acc = db.ref('rss/channel/item/4/title'); //**This worked!  */
        acc.set({
            entry: databaseEntry
        });
        return Promise.resolve('write complete')
            .then(_acc => {
                agent.add(`Wrote ${databaseEntry} to the realtime database.`);
                return false;
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
                agent.add(`Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
            });
    }
    // and this is when we want to write to in the same child, keeping the old values:
    //const acc = db.ref('/rss/channel/item/5/color'); //**This worked!  */
    //const result = acc.child(databaseEntry).set({entry: databaseEntry});
    //agent.add(`Wrote ${databaseEntry} to the realtime database.`);
    //console.log(result.key);
    //});

    // to read data
    function readFromDb(agent) {
        const any = agent.parameters.any;
        agent.add(`Thank you...`);
        var rootRef = db.ref();
        var childref = rootRef.child("rss/channel/item");
        return childref.orderByChild("title").equalTo("Icebreaker").once("value").then(function(snapshot){ //has been taken from the bus example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917390/dialogflow-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-through-in-a-firebase-query
            var colored = snapshot.child("color/__text").val();
            var sized = snapshot.child("size/__text").val();
            agent.add(`Your search result for ` + any + ` Throughout the database is ` + colored +
                ` Color and ` + sized + ` Size`);
            return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
        }).catch(() => {
            agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
            agent.add('Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
        });
    }


    // Map from Dialogflow intent names to functions to be run when the intent is matched
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('IWannaBuy', readFromDb);
    intentMap.set('WriteToFirebase', writeToDb);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});



    enter code here

[this is how my database is][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdFy5.png
```